# Why is my Antivurus finding a virus on StackOverflow?

Tags: virus, anti-virus, javascript, trojan

*This came as a total surprise to me.*

I am using Avast Antivirus `11.1.2253` with virus definitions version `160330-3` on a Windows 8.1 and a Firefox browser.

The issue: While reviewing some SO questions, my antivirus went crazy (*or not?*) and displayed me this pop-up

[image]

some sort of JS-Trojan but how? Has anyone idea why this could be happening? I kind of strongly believe that this might be false alert, but still not sure and amazed.

Has that happened to someone else?

*To recap: I am asking a question about a SO-virus on a SO-site..*

Comment: What happened when you clicked `Details`?

Comment: Its called a false positive, Avast is notorious, for having false positives.

Comment: Not much, the same info only with a green tick saying *"Infection blocked"*

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably a better to ask on meta.stackoverflow.com than here.

Comment: well, I thought about..it could still be migrated though